# Passing kwargs into get_or_create method in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a custom save function, where I want to perform certain functions based on a condition like this:

```
class ClassName(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        reindex =  **kwargs.pop("reindex")

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if reindex:
            People.objects.create()
```

Now inside a task I want to call the following:

```
kwargs = { "reindex": False}
ClassName.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
```

When it does a create, it obviously runs the save function, but it's giving me an error saying `reindex is not a field`.
I have been researching it for a while now and can't figure out what to do.
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

I just want to pass in an argument into the `get_or_create`, so that I can conditionally perform a certain function in the save method.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
kwargs = { "reindex": False}
ClassName.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
```

it is actually equivalent to

```
ClassName.objects.get_or_create(reindex=False)
```

Thus, since `reindex` appears not to be a field defined in the model `ClassName`, you get an error.

---

BTW, beyond things which appear erroneous, e.g. `reindex =  **kwargs.pop("reindex")`, you should define `reindex` as one of the fields of your model. But I admit that I answer blindly, because to me, your class definition cannot work like so. If one assumes that reindex is an integer field, you could do

```
class ClassName(models.Model):
    reindex = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if "reindex" in kwargs:
            People.objects.create()
```

Comment: I see! would you know, what I can do to get to get to my solution?

Comment: @Nazariy1995. Try this out. `makemigrations` and `migrate` then. Does it work ? It is unlikely since I do not what you actually try to perform.

Comment: I honestly ended up having to use a completely different way to do it without the user of kwargs. Thanks so much for the help